# How to calculate SQL column to fulfill below requirement

Tags: sql, pivot, qsqlquery

Currently I have my table as below:

[image: SourceTable]

I want to calculate and get values in new table like this:

[image: ReqTable]

Answer (score 1):

Try this, maybe it helps you.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #List
CREATE TABLE #List (
    Customer varchar(10),
    Month varchar(10),
    Sales float,
    Credit float
)
INSERT INTO #List VALUES
('Customer A', 'Jan', 1000, 454),
('Customer A', 'Feb', 10002, 3443)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Customer, Month, CONCAT(Sales, ' - ', Credit) AS Sales_Credit
    FROM #List
) AS DATA
PIVOT (MAX(Sales_Credit) FOR Month IN ([Jan], [Feb])) AS MultiplePivotTable
```

[You can see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5vKG.png)

If you're querying for a report such as SSRS, you can handle this so simple with matrix wizard.

**Edited part** (if you want only calculate and pivoting):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Customer, Month, (Sales - Credit) AS NetAmount
    FROM #List
) AS DATA
PIVOT (SUM(NetAmount) FOR Month IN ([Jan], [Feb])) AS PivotTable
```

Using PIVOT [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I Tried all the values comes as NULL. calculation did not happen